# Creating table from SQL Select statements and combining the results into a single record

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE "InitialsF"
AS(SELECT substr (Firstname,1,1) AS F
FROM PlayerDetails
UNION
SELECT substr (Surname ,1,1) AS S
FROM PlayerDetails);
```

I am trying to create an initials table, the player details are already in the PlayerDetails table. Is there a way to create a table from the results of the 2 SELECT substr queries?

And is there a way to combine the results of this query into a single column instead of 2 columns with the intial for the firstname and surname?

Thanks

Comment: Question why do you use UNION in this query? .. . Not sure whats thats about? Anyhow  see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the initials of each column:

```
CREATE TABLE "InitialsF" AS
SELECT substr(Firstname,1,1) || substr(Surname ,1,1) AS S
FROM PlayerDetails
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ewQ91VzeGYmXKEZ91QGwkA/0).